# Are Mongo DB text search scores comparable across queries?

Tags: mongodb, full-text-search

I know I can sort the results of a query based on the text score that each result has been assigned using MongoDB text search. But, given two different queries A and B that retrieve different documents D1 and D2, if `score(A, D1) > score(B, D2)` does it mean that D1 is more related to query A than D2 is to query B?

In other words, are the scores relative to the query or also valid absolutely?

Comment: I'm curious (although I don't think this affects the answer to your question): what is your use case for comparing different text search scores? Are these distinct queries against the same text index, or against different indexes?

Comment: I forgot to specify that the queries are against the same index. In my case I want to discard all the results whose score is under a threshold X: if the scores can only be compared relatively to the other ones in the same query this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

> given two different queries A and B that retrieve different documents D1 and D2, if score(A, D1) > score(B, D2) does it mean that D1 is more related to query A than D2 is to query B?

Assuming both queries are against equivalent text search indexes, the same scoring algorithm is used so this seems a correct inference to make.

Factors that can influence the scoring for queries would include text index options like:

- [field weights](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/control-results-of-text-search/)
- [language](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/specify-language-for-text-index/)
- `text` index version (eg: MongoDB 3.2 has [text search enhancements](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/3.2/#text-search-enhancements) associated with version 3 `text` indexes).

Comment: So there is no normalization going on for, for example, query length or other query-dependent factors? In my case, the index, weights and language are all the same)

Comment: The scoring is definitely query-dependent and there is normalization like stemming and tokenizing. However, I would consider that as part of the calculation to determine the relevance score. So `score(A,D1)` > `score(B,D2)` suggests that query A is more relevant to D1 than B is to D2, but doesn't convey any relevance for A to D2 or B to D1. If you are trying to blend results of query A and B, perhaps a logical OR in a single query makes more sense? https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#match-any-of-the-search-terms

Comment: Mmm, I'm not trying to blend results of the two query. I'll try to be more clear: let's say I set a threshold at 0.2 and I discard all the documents whose score is below this threshold: maybe for query A the scores range from 0.05 to 0.15 and for query B the scores are from 1.2 to 1.6 because of some normalization factors and now my threshold is irrelevant (or completely wrong). I don't know if that's quite clear, I hope so

Comment: Regardless of the range of scores (which will vary by query), the scoring algorithm will still be the same. So if your threshold is 0.75 this will have the same amount of calculated relevance across queries. Maybe this example of score calculation will help clarify: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37053453/1388319.